# Vorto Arduino Generator: no known conversion for argument from datatype Percentage

Tags: arduino, iot, bosch-iot-suite, eclipse-vorto

Vorto auto-generated code for Arduino won't compile when using Humidity Function Block

I generated an Information Model with both Temperature and Humidity Function block, and when compiling the Arduino auto-generated code, the Percentage Datatype won't compile

Here's a repository to the [Humidity Function Block](https://vorto.eclipse.org/#/details/org.eclipse.vorto:Humidity:1.0.0).

I expected the code to compile and flash to the NodeMCU V0.9

Here's the [full error message](https://hastebin.com/cezuwakuwo.http).

Comment: The relevant info should be included in the question itself.

Comment: The literal text of the code that does not compile and the resulting error must be included in the posting itself; links are *not acceptable* for this as they may die and policy requires that questions stand on their own.

Comment: As mentioned by others, OP please paste the error message in the question. The "hastebin" link shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

your problem might be related to https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/issues/1838 where Function Block properties named "value" conflict in the generated code with the param name "value". There the assignment results in value = value which has no effect. This problem has been fixed in 0.11.1 and we will roll out this patch later this week.

I can't access the full error log. Can you paste it into this thread ?

Comment: Thanks a lot
I edited the link with the error log, somebody changed it before

Comment: Still can't open. Nonetheless, we just released 0.11.1 with some fixes on the Arduino generator. Can you check if your problem exists with the latest version?